# Wait for promise to resolve before executing code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a service that calls a $http request and returns a JSONP . The returned JSONP from the API is either {valid:true} or {valid:false}. My code is:

```
    this.checkValid = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'API' + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
    }).then(function (response) {
        var temp = response.data.valid;
        return temp; //returns true or false


    }, function (response) {
        console.log('something   went wrong');
    })
}
```

I have another service that depends on the response returned from checkValid():

```
                var data = requestService.checkValid();
                var valid;
                //handling the promise
                data.then(function (response) {
                    valid = response;
                    console.log('Inside the then block : ' + valid);
                });

                if (valid)
                    console.log('Valid!');
                else
                    console.log('Not Valid!');
```

The output is (after the api returns valid:true) :

```
'Not valid'
'Not valid'
'Not valid'
'Not valid'
'Inside the then block : true'
'Inside the then block : true'
'Inside the then block : true'
'Inside the then block : true'
```

I would like to know how to wait for the `then()` to complete, setting `value` to `true` or `false`, then going to the `if` statement.

Comment: you can use promise ($q) to ensure you return result and then execute next. have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

[You can never return a value from asynchronous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function).

```
            data.then(function (response) {
                valid = response;
                console.log('Inside the then block : ' + valid);
            });
```

`valid = response` is asynchronous (it will be executed when `then` is triggered). You cannot use this value outside that context (i.e. in your `if`). If you need to use the response, use it right there in the `then` function, or return a promise, and continue processing with another `then`.

Comment: async/await is a solution. there are multiple transforms in babel that convert async_/await calls to ES5 -- so it is plainly possible.

Comment: @robertotomás: `async/await` is a syntactic sugar for promises (which is exactly how babel converts them into ES5), so I do not think I have said anything incorrect. Besides, consider when the answer was written - `async/await` were not in any specification yet. They still aren't; they are planned for ES2018.

Comment: where you said "You can **never** return a value from asynchronous function." (emphasis mine), you were incorrect. async/await _is_ syntactic sugar -- or rather, really it is standard ES6 -- but the babel polyfill and plugin-async-to-promises for example, converts that syntax to standard CJS. So it seems to be possible. I didn't vote you down or anything, btw. I basically agree with you. Just noting that some form of transform is generalizable.

Comment: @robertotomás: We seem to interpret "return" differently. As I said, an `async` function returns a Promise, always, not a "returned" value: `const f = async function() { return 17; }; console.log(f());` gives `Promise`, not `17`; and is thus covered by "... or return a promise..." in the answer.

Comment: no, we have no disagreement about the keyword `return`. You are confusing `async/await` with just `async` by itself. he wants to know how to modify a function so an _inner codepoint_ in the function returns immediately. this is the purpose of `await` in an `async/await` function. such that: `let foo = async asAPromise() => await bar()` will assign the result of `bar()` to `foo` immediately .. I am not sure but I believe `async` flags the parent function of the async section of code that must be refactored and `await` flags the actual code to convert to blocking form

Comment: @robertotomás: No parent function marking goes on, and refactoring is not a part of the [draft specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions). I am not confusing anything; you seem to be confusing babel operation with language definition. `async` is dead easy: it wraps the function into a promise-returning function (and marks that function as async, which changes its grammar rules and constructor). `await`, when inside `async`-marked function, will accept *any* promise (such as one returned by an async function, but *any* promise will do), and linearise it.

Comment: @robertotomás: One can talk about `async` and `await` separately, though of course they cooperate well.  Here's the other side of the equation, `await`-ing a bare promise, instead of another `async`'d function: `z = async function() { let p = new Promise((good, bad) => good(17)); return await p; }; z().then(x => console.log(x))`. The fact remains, `async` function [returns a promise](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions-EvaluateBody).

Comment: Im going to stop responding in this thread since this is clearly becoming an argument to you. I was not responding to your use of `async/await`, you were responding to my use of `async/await` .. where I clearly said it can be converted to commonJS, such as with babel, and therefor an in-line return should be possible, even if the code points involved are more than just the one active code point. Let's just chill, I'm not into arguing over word choice.